# Debug release build in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, clang

I'm fairly new to qt, so sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm trying to keep debug symbols in a release build on linux.

Most of what I've read has todo with qmake which we dont use. Our project is a makefile project using clang. I have the -g in the release build of my makefile, but when a raise() is called, I'm dumped to assembly which is a little hard for me to debug :) And breakpoints just don't work.

I've tried from what I've read.

- In Run - Enable QML
- In Kits Debugger - Uncheck warn when debugging release builds (this was a tip)

Comment: How is this 'off topic' Does it not fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: Shouldn't `CONFIG += debug` do the trick?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build Qt in "Release with Debug Info" mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993061/build-qt-in-release-with-debug-info-mode)

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Don't think its a dup, I had read that before, but using qmake, which we aren't using as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

What I did first was to add `-g` to the release part of my makefile, but qt still didn't pickup the debug symbols.

So in reverse I added `-03` to the debug part of the makefile, which allowed me to debug the optimised code.